# Can you import the BUILD_ID of a cloud build into your Cloud Run python container?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-memorystore

We want to use django's redis cache feature that allows us to specify version numbers which will effectively invalidate cache values of a previous build (before the code changed).

GCP's Cloud build has a default $BUILD_ID value available to the build yaml files, but is there a way for a deployed container to access this BUILD_ID value? If we could, we could us it (or a modulo value of it) to be our unique cache version.

- See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values for GCP build variables
- See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#cache-arguments for django cache documentation

Answer (score 1):

Use [Method:prjects.builds.list](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/list) API, you could use this API to get all list, and also you can query pageSize to get the number of results in the list.

When you get [response](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build) from the API, you can just do what you want with your $BUILD_ID

I hope this information above is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cloudbuild.yaml` file can pass substitution variables into a container you are deploying by using the `set-env-vars` flag.

```
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - id: "deploy"
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - '${_SERVICE_NAME}'
      - '--image'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_SERVICE_NAME}:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--region=${_DEPLOY_REGION}'
      - '--vpc-connector redis'
      - '--set-env-vars REDISHOST=${_REDIS_HOST},REDISPORT=${_REDIS_PORT},BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID'
```

Here we pass `_REDIS_HOST` and `_REDIS_PORT` and `BUILD_ID` into the container as `REDISHOST`, `REDISPORT` and `BUILD_ID`.

We can now read these within python like so:

settings.py file:

```
...

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDISHOST', 'localhost')
redis_port = int(os.environ.get('REDISPORT', 6379))
build_id = int(os.environ.get('BUILD_ID', None))
```